# Plotting Vectors in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm trying to plot 2D vectors in Mathematica. Built in functions don't really work for me because I want to plot vectors of matrices from the origin to the  their coordinates with an arrow on their tips.  I made a function

```
plotMatrixVectors[mat_List] := 
 Graphics[Table[Arrow[{origin, i}], {i, mat}], Axes -> True],
```

and it worked just fine, until it suddenly stopped working and instead of a graph started reporting this to me:

```
{{plotMatrixVectors[1], plotMatrixVectors[2]}, {plotMatrixVectors[3], 
  plotMatrixVectors[1]}}
```

Note: these numbers in square bracket have nothing to the with coordinates in the lower example, this message came up when I tried to plot different vectors, but you get the point.

I rewrote the function because I thought I unintentionally messed it up somehow, but it still printed the same thing. However, when I copypasted the body of the function and just plugged in a 2x2 matrix, say this one

```
plot2D1 = {{1, 5}, {-6, 4}};

Graphics[Table[Arrow[{origin, i}], {i, plot2D1}], Axes -> True]
```

it gives me this, which is good. 
[image]

I have 2 questions here.
1) Why did my function stopped working but the same thing works when it's typed outside of the function? I restarted Mathematica and it still didn't work.
2) Is there any way to strecth those axes so they go beyond the limits of matrix vectors coordinates?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the exact command you're typing when it gives the bad output? Without seeing an example, I'm going to guess that you're trying to give it a list with the wrong dimensions and `Table` isn't behaving the way you expect.

Comment: Sure, here it is:


origin = {0, 0};

matrix = {{1, 2}, {-4, 5}};

plotMatrixVectors[mat_List] := 
 Graphics[Table[Arrow[{origin, i}], {i, mat}], Axes -> True]

plotMatrixVectors[matrix]

Out[232]= {{plotMatrixVectors[1],  plotMatrixVectors[2]}, {plotMatrixVectors[-4], 
  plotMatrixVectors[5]}}


Sorry for this mess, don't know how to properly copy it. Hope you'll spot something, 'cause I've tried again and still I see nothing wrong

Comment: @NikolaKojadinović It is unlikely that that is a full report.  The function works fine.  The result you're getting is equivalent to `plotMatrixVectors /@ Catenate@matrix`.

Comment: @Alan it is a full report. However, it works fine now after I restarted mathematica 5 times. Do you think it could've been a bug?

Comment: thank you guys anyways. and now that it works fine, do you have any idea how to stretch axes so I can see more of the coordinate system?

Comment: You could have had a definition you forgot to clear. Otherwise it's very hard to say what's going on if something like that goes away after a restart. If it shows up again, check back. See the docs on the option `PlotRange' for the axes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong with your code, but you might try this. It is simpler and more robust than your formulation.

```
plotVectors[pts : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} __}] := 
  Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #} & /@ pts], Axes -> True]
```

Tests

```
plotVectors[{{1, 5}, {-6, 4}}
```

[image: test1]

```
SeedRandom[26];
With[{n = 15}, plotVectors[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, 2}]]]
```

[image: test2]

Comment: `plotVectors[pts : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} __}] ` I've never seen that construction before. Came here to learn something.

Comment: @m_goldberg wow, that was neat. thanks a lot!

Comment: @NikolaKojadinović. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: @m_goldberg accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into an error, add a comma after the first nested bracket: `plotVectors[pts : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}, __}]`.

Comment: Does this work with just one vector? It doesn't work as expected here, but perhaps I messed up.

Comment: I'm pretty puzzled by the `__` on the end. Did you actually mean `plotVectors[pts : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} ..}] := Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #} & /@ pts], Axes -> True]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show this code, which is essentially the same as from m_goldberg, but it uses Standard colors. And adds label, the reason I did this, is because I needed this on my own plots and wanted to share.

```mathematica
plotVector[vectors : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} ..}, 
   OptionsPattern[{"Label" -> False}]] := 
  Block[{arrows, labels}, 
   arrows = 
    MapIndexed[
     Style[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #1}], ColorData[97][#2[[1]]], Thick] &, 
     vectors];
   labels = 
    MapIndexed[
     Style[Text[#1, #1 + {0.2, 0.2}, {1, 1}], 
       ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, vectors];
   Graphics[
    Join[{Arrowheads[0.05]}, arrows, 
     If[OptionValue["Label"], labels, {}]], Axes -> True]];
```

This function takes a list of 2D vectors as input and plots them as arrows on a 2D plot, with the origin `{0, 0}` as the starting point and the vector as the end point. The arrows are styled using the Style function, with the color generated using the `ColorData` function and the thickness specified using the Thick option. The x-axis and y-axis are displayed on the plot using the Axes option, and the size of the arrowheads is specified using the Arrowheads option.

You use it like this:
`plotVector[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Label -> True]`, in order to get:

[image: Mathematica screenshot plotting the result of plotVector[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Label -> True]]